# How can I use restore mongodb with MupX since mongodb is inside docker container?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, deployment

I used mongodump to backup my database since I want to move it from being hosted at compose.io to being hosted locally in the server itself using mupx.

Once I setup the app and have it running, how can I restore the mongodump? I am using mupx, and when I ssh into the server I see that mongodb is inside a docker container.

What are the steps needed to use mongorestore given that I can copy the mongodump files from my local pc to the server.

1) Use scp command to copy the mongodump folder from my local pc to the server
2) SSH into the server

At this point I am logged into the server and am in the same directory as the dump folder. Mongodb is running inside docker. How can I use mongorestore to restore mongodb to the data in the dump folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Here are step by step instructions.

Here are the instructions

1) Copy dump folder to server

```
scp -r /local_path/to/dump_folder root@111.222.33.4:/remote/path
```

2) SSH into server

```
ssh root@111.222.33.4
```

3) Copy from root of server to inside docker container

```
docker cp dump_folder mongodb:/dump_folder
```

4) Go into mongodb docker container

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
```

5) check if copied folder exists

```
ls (you should see dump_folder, if you named it the same folder as in this example)
```

6) use mongorestore

```
mongorestore --drop -d AppName dump_folder
```

Comment: Thank you for these great instructions, they worked and I couldn't find this information anywhere else.

However, my live app now keeps showing error messages like:

GET http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/favicon-32x32.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

and failing to find icons, or temporarily failing to find the page at all.

Any idea why this might be happening? It all runs fine locally. Meteor 1.6 deployed to a Digital Ocean droplet with mup.

Comment: mup setup gives this error: Error response from daemon: Cannot update container a3cf59897da6d21dae4e2cbb3dcc9bd9dadc9aa07637cefa2233ec09c96cf6a6: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: connect: connection refused": unknown
 Error response from daemon: Could not kill running container a3cf59897da6d21dae4e2cbb3dcc9bd9dadc9aa07637cefa2233ec09c96cf6a6, cannot remove - Cannot kill container a3cf59897da6d21dae4e2cbb3dcc9bd9dadc9aa07637cefa2233ec09c96cf6a6: connection error: desc = "transport: dial unix

Answer (score 0):

For example: you copied mongo dump file to /data folder of server.

While you run docker container, you can mount /data folder into docker container.

```
docker run -v /data:/var/lib/mongodb -p 27017 ....
```

After that, you access to inside docker container and go to /var/lib/mongodb. You can see mongo dump file here by using : ls command. 
Here, you can use mongorestore to restore mongo data.

Comment: when I run the command you specified to mount data folder to docker container I get error: `Unable to find image 'mongodb:latest' locally` Thus I cannot continue

Comment: This meant you haven't built mongodb image in locally,yet.  Are you sure you have built mongo image?